# Click the screen when a certain pixel turns a certain color

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

Hobby script kiddo here

I'm trying to make a bot that can beat humans at reaction quizes (such as [this one](https://humanbenchmark.com/tests/reactiontime)). However, I think my code be more efficient and respond quicker.

The code I have below averages around 130 ms respond time.

```
import pandas as pd
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageGrab
import time
import pyautogui
import mouse
abc123=0
time.sleep(0)
while abc123==0:
    im1 = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(50, 150, 700, 400)) #x, y, w, h
    img_np = np.array(im1)
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(img_np, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    break
index=["color", "color_name", "hex", "R", "G", "B"]
csv = pd.read_csv(r'D:\code\colors1.csv', names=index, header=None)
clicked = False
r = g = b = xpos = ypos = 0


def recognize_color(R,G,B):
    minimum = 10000
    for i in range(len(csv)):
        d = abs(R- int(csv.loc[i,"R"])) + abs(G- int(csv.loc[i,"G"]))+ abs(B- int(csv.loc[i,"B"]))
        if(d<=minimum):
            minimum = d
            cname = csv.loc[i,"color_name"]
    return cname

def mouse_click(event, x, y, flags, param):
    if True:
        global b,g,r,xpos,ypos, clicked
        clicked = True
        xpos = x
        ypos = y
        b,g,r = frame[y,x]
        b = int(b)
        g = int(g)
        r = int(r)



cv2.namedWindow('Color Recognition App')
cv2.setMouseCallback('Color Recognition App', mouse_click)
run_once = 0
pyautogui.click(x=200, y=150)
time.sleep(0)
while(1):
    im1 = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(50, 150, 700, 400)) #x, y, w, h
    img_np = np.array(im1)
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(img_np, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    mouse.move(1,1, absolute=False)
    mouse.move(-1,-1, absolute=False)
    cv2.imshow("Color Recognition App",frame)
    if (clicked):
        # print(g)
        if g in range(200,250):
                pyautogui.click(x=470, y=300)
    clicked=False
    #Break the loop when user hits 'esc' key    
    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF ==27:
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

```
csv = pd.read_csv(r'D:\code\colors1.csv', names=index, header=None)
```

requires this file -> https://file.io/mXCore9FqusW

Comment: "*requires this file -> https://file.io/AdXa8vhTSwZL*", **file deleted** !!

Comment: your post contains no uses of the `mouse_callback` identifier that you mention. pyautogui.click will take no time at all, so your worries there are misplaced. -- perhaps you wanna use a **profiler** on your code.

Answer (score 0):

Played around a little, made one that averages 60ms:

```
import PIL.ImageGrab
import mouse
while True:
    rgb = PIL.ImageGrab.grab().load()[75,180]
    rgb2=(78, 221, 113)
    if rgb == rgb2:
        mouse.click()
```